# best way to evaluate a function over each element of a dataframe or array using pandas, numpy or others

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some time series data that requires multiplying constants by variables at time t. I have come up with 3 methods to get an answer that is correct.

The main thing I am wondering is Q1 below. I appreciate Q2 and Q3 could be subjective, but I am mostly seeing if there is a much better method I am completely missing.

- Q1. Is there a much better way to implement this formula across a
  dataframe/array that I have missed (i.e. not one of these three
  methods in the code)? If so please let me know.

More subjectively... I could time each method and choose one purely by the most time efficient method, I was wondering:

- Q2. Are any of these certain methods preferred as they are clearer /
  better written / use less resource / more 'Pythonic'?
- Q3. Or is it just the case that any of these 3 are absolutely fine
  and it is just a preference thing? One large reason I ask is that I
  often hear people trying to shy away from loops...

The formula to be applied is:

```
ans_t = x * var1_t + (1 - x) * var2_t - y * max(0, var3_t - z)
```

note: _t means at time t

Due to the time series nature of it, I could not get something like this to work:

```
x * df['var1'] + (1 - x) * df['var2'] - y * max(0, df['var3'] - z)
```

Therefore I went for the 3 methods below:

```
# %%
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [6, 8, 11, 15, 10], 'var2': [1, 8, 2, 15, 4], 'var3': [21, 82, 22, 115, 64]})

# constants
x = 0.44
y = 1.68
z = 22

# function to evaluate: ans_t = x * var1_t + (1 - x) * var2_t - y * max(0, var3_t - z)
# note: _t means at time t


# %%
# ---- Method 1: use simple for loop ----
df['ans1'] = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
    df['ans1'][i] = x * df['var1'][i] + (1 - x) * df['var2'][i] - y * max(0, df['var3'][i] - z)


# %%
# ---- Method 2: apply a lambda function ----
def my_func(var1, var2, var3):
    return x * var1 + (1 - x) * var2 - y * max(0, var3 - z)


df['ans2'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['var1'], x['var2'], x['var3']), axis=1)

# %%
# ---- Method 3: numpy vectorize ----
df['ans3'] = np.vectorize(my_func)(df['var1'], df['var2'], df['var3'])
```

Comment: The reason to avoid loops is speed.  Actually what we try to avoid is interpreted python loops.  If compiled numpy and python code can do the task it will (usually) be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.maximum` (note: not the same as `np.max`) gives a vectorized way of handling the `max` element of the formula:

```
df['ans_t'] = x * df['var1'] + (1 - x) * df['var2'] - y * np.maximum(0, df['var3'] - z)
```

after which `df['ans_t']` is:

```
0      3.20
1    -92.80
2      5.96
3   -141.24
4    -63.92
Name: ans_t, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is incredibly elegant. Can you explain how this works in the background? Does it just loop through each element in the 'var3' series and determine the max, then loop through each series element in 'var1' and 'var2' to calculate the rest?

Comment: The order of execution will be the usual Python one (so bracketed expressions are evaluated first, multiplication happens before addition etc, then all else being equal it's left-to-right).  I don't know all the low-level internals, but when an operation involving series is taking place, the Pandas/Numpy C code will use loops to chunk the series into groups of elements, and within those loops use the ability of the CPU to perform math operations on all the elements of a small vector simultaneously (SIMD instructions).  That all ends up much faster than doing an explicit Python loop...

Comment: ...or the implicit loops that happen when you call `pd.apply` or `np.vectorize`.

Comment: That is much clearer now - appreciate the explanation